# SQL Array into Array based function

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, phirehose

Default Set Up

```
$stream->setTrack (array('cookie'));
```

Trial

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT text FROM keywords"; $query = mysql_query($sql) or die($sql . ' - ' . mysql_error());
$keys = array();
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
 $keys[] = $row[0];
}$stream->setTrack ($keys);
```

The default set up takes the written word and places it into an array
The trial set up should retrieve a set of keywords from a mysql table as an array and insert them into the function.

It doesn't work. What's wrong?

```
public function setTrack($trackWords)
{
$trackWords = ($trackWords === NULL) ? array() : $trackWords;
sort($trackWords); // Non-optimal, but necessary
if ($this->trackWords != $trackWords) {
  $this->filterChanged = TRUE;
}
$this->trackWords = $trackWords;
}
```

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with this code. Perhaps the problem is inside the `setTrack` method? I would suggest turning on error reporting and see if there are any errors. Also, what is the expected output and what are you getting? `It doesn't work` doesn't tell us a whole lot.

Comment: The array from the database is not being converted into the appropriate format i.e. 'cookie','recipe'

Comment: Are you sure? try to do a print_r of the $keys array after the while loop.

Comment: Yes, print_r output= Array ( [0] => cookie [1] => dough [2] => ice cream  [3] => recipe). I think the setTrack function can only take entries in the format 'cookie','dough' but I don't know how to get to that format. Thanks